# Ampersand escaped to 'u0026' after a CNAME redirect

Tags: kubernetes

I'm configuring a service in Kubernetes in such a way, that nodejs calls another server outside of the cluster. In order to achieve that, i have defined a service in kubernetes, that looks like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name:  my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.external.domain
```

As expected, the CNAME redirect works correctly, but when the call contains an ampersand '&' is escaped to 'u0026. Is there a way to avoid this escaping???